How to model Capacitated VRP for planning monthly schedule and multiple visits per customer?
We have tried the quick-start for Vehicle Routing and am now looking to extend the code to our use case of doing route planning given a forward planning window of one month. No pre-order, and each customer will be visited a few times (Visit needs defined per customer), with visits being as evenly spaced out as possible to maximise sales at each visit. The vehicleCapacity constraint also has to be reset each day of course during solving.
We are new to Timefold, so trying to modify the model based on the above, but was just wondering if there are any reference models/quick start with code that we should be looking at given the requirements above?
Cheers
Han
We tried the quick-start for Vehicle Routing, and am looking to extend that with a good model.

Given the vehicles represent people driving them and providing service during their working hours, one possibility of expressing multi-day vehicle routing can be projecting vehicles to individual working days.
This projection (vehicle per day) becomes the planning entity instead of the vehicle and also allows for tracking the capacity on a daily basis.
